# How can I change the result of an SQL query?

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is possible, but I want to change the value of a result that's given by a query. For example, here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `entity_id`)
FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE (entity_type_id='4')
```

I want this query to always return X instead of the real value of the result.

EDIT: Should have been more specific. I DO NOT have access to the code calling this query.

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense in the context you've given.  Why would you aggregate the count if you just wanted to return a static number?  e.g.  `SELECT 5`

Comment: X is a string, any random value, something you pass in...? Or where to find the treasure?

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more specific. Basically, I can't change the query because I don't have access to the query. The query could return 1615 but I want it to always show a different number. Like I said, not sure if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hard code your value then you would just do the following:

```
SELECT 'X'
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `entity_id`) 
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` 
    WHERE (entity_type_id='4')
) As MySearch
```

Not sue why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a constant.

SELECT 5;

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have access to this query, you can do this:

`SELECT X FROM table`

It will always return X, but I am not sure if that's what you meant :D

Comment: You wouldn't even need to select from a table to do this.  You could just `SELECT X`

Comment: @George: or not even make a SQL call...?

Comment: @gbn Hahaha, yes or that too. ;)

Comment: I think I should SELECT from special dual table in ORACLE, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need something like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `entity_id`) as 'X'
FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE (entity_type_id='4')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the code (as per your comment on the question), you can't make it return something different. Different code will return something different...

So "not possible" unless changes can be made to the query

Unless you can "hide" or "mask" the table `catalog_product_entity_int` so it's your table with, say, 1615 rows in it. But this depends on no other query using this table. In SQL Server you could use synonyms or schemas: not sure how you'd achieve this (if practical) in MySQL)